# why am I getting error by using JXDatePicker class

Tags: java

I am getting such type error :-

```
DatePickerExample.java:5: error: package org.jdesktop.swingx does not exist
import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker;
                          ^
DatePickerExample.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        JXDatePicker picker = new JXDatePicker();
        ^
  symbol:   class JXDatePicker
  location: class DatePickerExample
DatePickerExample.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        JXDatePicker picker = new JXDatePicker();
                                  ^
  symbol:   class JXDatePicker
  location: class DatePickerExample
3 errors
```

Even I am using jdk version :-
java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

please some one help me I am supposed to use such component in my project.

Answer (score 2):

`swingx` is not part of the jdk. You need to acquire the jar and include it in your classpath.

Comment: To be honest I didn't look at the error as it wasn't formatted when I answered. +1